# How to build moveit configuration package for fanuc R-2000iC/210F

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have some developments that I want to test on the following Fanuc robot  `R-2000iC/210F`. I have found that [fanuc experimental](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc_experimental) lists a support package `fanuc_r2000ic_support`. This package contains configuration data, 3D models and launch files for Fanuc R-2000iC manipulators. Can I use **moveit setup assistant**,  loading the urdf from `~/catkin_ws/src/fanuc_experimental/fanuc_r2000ic_support/urdf/r2000ic210f.xacro`, and following the steps on MSA wizard to generate moveit configuration pacakge for the /210F model?

thanks,

Zahid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382643/how-to-build-moveit-configuration-package-for-fanuc-r-2000ic/210f/) by [zahid990170](https://answers.ros.org/users/50178/zahid990170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 135 on 2021-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can I use **moveit setup assistant**,  loading the urdf from `~/catkin_ws/src/fanuc_experimental/fanuc_r2000ic_support/urdf/r2000ic210f.xacro`, and following the steps on MSA wizard to generate moveit configuration pacakge for the /210F model?

yes.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zahid990170](https://answers.ros.org/users/50178/zahid990170/) on 2021-07-17**:
thanks @gvdhoorn, MSA did not generate `moveit_planning_execution.launch` file. Also, needed to confirm the following settings were correct: `virtual_joint:`, child link: base_link, parent frame name: world, joint type: fixed. `planning group:` arm, kinematic chain: base_link to link_6. `planning_group:` hand, joints: joint6-flange, link_6-tool0. `End effector:` group name: hand, parent link: link_6, parent group: arm, `ROS_control:` FollowJointsTrajectory, thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-17**:
I'd refer you to: [Create a MoveIt Package for an Industrial Robot](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_MoveIt_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot).